# Improve pandas iterate, subset and merge performance

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance

I have a dataframe with users and roles and another df with incompatible roles. The challenge is finding who has incompatible roles.
I found one solution with df.apply with a function who segment users and roles, and merge it. The results is good but the performance need to be improved: to process 500.000 records need 1.5 hours.
Is it possible to reduce the time of this process?

```
df_usr = pd.DataFrame({"user": ('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
                   "role": ('role_1', 'role_2', 'role_3', 'role_3', 'role_4', 'role_5', 'role_6', 'role_5', 'role_6', 'role_7', 'role_1', 'role_2'),
                  })
df_inc = pd.DataFrame({"role": ('role_1', 'role_1', 'role_3', 'role_3', 'role_5', 'role_7', 'role_7'),
                   "incomp": ('role_2', 'role_3', 'role_2', 'role_4', 'role_6', 'role_5', 'role_6')
                  })

class get_incomp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.df_final = pd.DataFrame()

    def get_incomp(self, user, role):
        df_u = df_usr[df_usr["user"] == user]
        df_i = df_inc[df_inc["role"] == role]
        df_r = pd.merge(left=df_u, right=df_i, left_on="role", right_on="incomp", suffixes=["_u", "_i"])
        self.df_final = pd.concat([self.df_final, df_r])

    def fin(self):
        self.df_final = self.df_final[["user", "role_u", "role_i"]]
        return self.df_final

inc = get_incomp()
df_usr.apply(lambda row: inc.get_incomp(row["user"], row["role"]), axis=1)
df_fin = inc.fin()
```

Comment: Try this `df_usr.merge(df_usr, on='user').merge(df_inc, left_on=['role_x', 'role_y'], right_on=['role','incomp'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tmp = pd.merge(df_usr, df_inc, on="role")
df_fin = pd.merge(
    tmp, df_usr, left_on=["user", "incomp"], right_on=["user", "role"]
)[["user", "incomp", "role_x"]].rename(
    columns={"incomp": "role_u", "role_x": "role_i"}
)
print(df_fin)
```

Prints:

```
  user  role_u  role_i
0    A  role_2  role_1
1    A  role_2  role_3
2    A  role_3  role_1
3    C  role_2  role_1
4    B  role_4  role_3
5    B  role_6  role_5
6    C  role_6  role_5
7    C  role_6  role_7
8    C  role_5  role_7
```

---

Then you can `.sort_values()`:

```
print(df_fin.sort_values("user"))

  user  role_u  role_i
0    A  role_2  role_1
1    A  role_2  role_3
2    A  role_3  role_1
4    B  role_4  role_3
5    B  role_6  role_5
3    C  role_2  role_1
6    C  role_6  role_5
7    C  role_6  role_7
8    C  role_5  role_7
```

Comment: Time spending on this process was reduced from 1.5 hours to 5.30 minutes. Great improvement! Thanks @Andrej !!

Comment: @dan That's quite an improvement! :) Glad to help...